# Al intentar documentar en Swagger UI un id que es de tipo ObjectID, arroja el error Value not declarable with JSON Schema

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi

Estoy utilizando FastAPI y pydantic 1.10, y al intentar documentar en Swagger UI un id que es de tipo ObjectID, me arroja un error.

```
from typing import Optional 
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, EmailStr
from bson import ObjectId
# Clase PyObjectId #
class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
@classmethod
def __get_validators__(cls):
yield cls.validate
@classmethod
def validate(cls, v):
if not ObjectId.is_valid(v):
raise ValueError('Invalid ObjectId')
return str(v)
# Configuraciones Clase PyObjectId #
class Config:
orm_mode = True
allow_population_by_field_name = True
json_encoders = { ObjectId: str }
class UserBase(BaseModel):
id: Optional[PyObjectId] = Field(alias='_id')
```

Me arroja el siguiente error al acceder a *http://localhost:8000/docs*:

> ValueError: Value not declarable with JSON Schema, field: name='id' type=Optional[PyObjectId] required=False default=None alias='_id

Comment: Recuerda que en Python el indentado es _crítico_. Pon tu código _tal cual como lo tienes_, y agrega triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después de tal código, para darle el formato correspondiente.

Comment: Por cierto, no dejes abandonadas tus preguntas anteriores... Procura autorresponderlas si ya encontraste solución. Y el código, siempre _como texto, con formato_.